Why are sink drain pipes 1 1/8 to 1 1/4 inches in [outer] diameter when p-traps are 1.5 inches?
I have four sink drains to work with (well actually three plus a garbage disposal from the kitchen). All of them have 1 1/8 to 1 1/4 inch OD descending pipes.  I also have a gaggle of your basic p-traps: all of those fit loosely / slip when inserting  1.25 Outer diameter pipes (let alone 1 1/8" !)

Now I could go and hunt down a handful of couplers I suppose but am I missing something easier/simpler/cheaper here?  This is so common then why is an extra piece apparently always required?

I believe sink drains need to be bigger than 1 inch now.  What is the inside diameter of the red washer?

@crip659 The drains are for pop up sink drains or a garbage disposal purchased within the past three months on amazon.  The red washer is perfect for a 1.25 inch tube: these are all 1.0

Three different sites on a fast search/read all say 1.25 inch is the smallest standard/common size.  Amazon is not known to always supply stuff that meets code.

The drain pictured above is a  Kohler  so we're actually working with at least one name brand part here.  The OD is 1 1/8 and the ID is 1.0

What is Kohler model #? Perhaps you somehow acquired fixtures intended for markets other than the US with its standard drain sizes?

@kreemoweet I can go on amazon and see moen drains with 1 3/16 OD so its not the  case of 1 1/4 being a set standard afaict.   I have drains for three different types of items and all are one inch.  I have not run into a mixup with international sizes except rarely and this is too much evidence to the contrary in my estimation.  I wonder why they do not include adapters at the least.  I actually have not found any online yet either.  Presesntly at Ace hardware and nothing here though this is a small store admittedly.

TL/DR aka Final result
I found that a very specific pair of washers on the drain downpipe to ptrap coupler provides a tight seal without the  need for pipe threads.  These are both needed:

red one reduces from 1 1/2" to 1 1/4" but only "more or less" !  It is called a Keeney 1-1/2-in Rubber Flanged Tailpiece Washer
white one provides a tight seal on the 1 1/4" pipe (but it would be too narrow to work with the nut by itself) . It is called a 1-1/4 Inch Slip Joint Washer


The second of the two drains is here: it has the tubular p-trap instead of the original pvc

**Historical background for the answer **
In this [excellent] Youtube video for connecting a faucet drain there is a shot of the final product that does show a piece that would appear to be the "missing link" [it's friends with a creature called 'Lucy'].   This one has a wider outside diameter that matches properly to the input side of the P-trap:

Now I just need to find that part..
Update. OK it's called a Slip joint Extension (with nut and washer) .  I am purchasing both 1 1/4" and 1 1/2" varieties from Amazon and will see which one works better.
Update Received it this afternoon and it is installed and not leaking.  I did need to put an artificial ring of pipe thread that continues to confound a bit.. But noone can present a "it just works" solution so I'm rolling with it

On the sink basin a bead of silicone was placed under the lip. I will subsequently clean up the excess.

*Update In response to @jay613's comment about the pvc trap:
Yes it is PVC: for the latest piping endeavor I am re-using what was already there but there is no difference in diameter vs the off-the-shelf _tubular+ [and the original post was based on tubular not pvc]:


I have removed my other comments here, and rewritten my answer in a way that I hope will help you to understand the problems you're having and how to solve them.

@jay613. I read your answer and have commented there. My answer  addresses the actual issues encountered.

There are mainly two kinds of pipe used for under-sink traps: PVC and Tubular.  Tubular comes in 1-1/4 and 1-1/2 inch sizes.  PVC also comes in those, and many other sizes.
The problem you are having is mixing both the two types and different sizes of pipe.
The outer diameter of tubular pipes is exactly the nominal diameter.  A 1-1/4 trap has 1-1/4 pipes and the slip joints designed to fit it.
The OD of PVC is: 1-1/4 is 1.66 inches, 1-1/2 is 1.9 inches.  PVC traps with slip joints are designed to accommodate those sizes.
There are ways to correctly combine systems and sizes.

To mate a 1-1/4 tubular pipe to a 1-1/2 tubular slip joint you use a reducing washer.
To mate a tubular pipe to a PVC system you use a trap adapter.  There are trap adapters for various combinations EG a 1-1/2 x 1-1/4 trap adapter mates a 1-1/2 PVC pipe to a 1-1/4 tubular pipe.
Those are the common ways to do things by design.  There are other correct ways to switch sizes and systems, especially when retrofitting, and including rubber couplings that are quite versatile.

If you mix and match things incorrectly, they won't work very well.  In particular, a 1-1/2 inch tubular pipe (1.50 inches) seems to fit into a 1-1/4 inch PVC slip joint (1.66 inches).  There is a 2-mm gap all around that might, sometimes, be made up by forcing a washer deep into the gap or using incorrect parts.  This is unreliable.   Also, where a trap arm meets the trap the joint is not a slip joint, and can sometimes be a little more forgiving, and depending on manufacturer it may even work well.  This can give a false sense of security.  You shouldn't mix systems except as noted above with reducing washers or trap adapters, or if necessary rubber couplings used correctly.
All of the problems you've shown in your question, comments, and photos here can be explained by the above and can be corrected by intently buying and using correct parts designed for one another.  I can't emphasize this enough: If you have two parts that don't seem to fit together properly, and you didn't buy them yourself and don't know where they came from or what exactly they are .... don't waste your time.  Throw it all out, go buy a kit, all from one manufacturer, of parts designed to do what you want to do and you'll get the whole job done in 10 minutes with no hacking.

I have tried a half dozen different tail pipes from various sellers including off the shelf from Ace. This appears to be a general complication that is not however much described.   I will be in receipt of these additional pieces tonight and will update the answer accordingly.

The slip-joint provides the starting point for the missing piece. I did still need to put in a pipe-thread artificial shim because the washers aren't snug enough.  No ready made solution exists per my extensive investigation.

Please remove the aspects of PVC vs tubular: as described in my answer the issues remain the same across both types.   My answer also describes the need for a pair of specific washers : and those are different from the ones that come with the tubular ptrap kits.   This answer is well thought out but oversimplifies the problem and does not resolve the actual issues encountered.

You seem to be saying that it is impossible to go out and buy a set of fittings that allow you to easily plumb a basin to a drain, that the only way to do it is to hack together random ill-fitting parts in the manner you have done, and that the 4 million or so basins installed in new homes in the USA every year cannot possibly be assembled without your innovation.    YOu can't possibly be saying that ... what am I missing about your situation or your question?   What limits you from doing this the vanilla way?

I have described the limitations /problems and my surprise that it takes so much effort is no less than would be expected.   The fittings are loose and do leak when following the herd path.
